# Complex foreach example

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

`Index.php` is built from data of `domains.php`. How can I create these tables and options in `domains.php` dynamically with `foreach` function?

**domains.php**

```
<?php

$price=array(

  "cz"=>    "20",
  "com"=>   "10",
  "net"=>   "8",
  "org"=>   "8",
  "info"=>  "8",
  "biz"=>   "8",
  "name"=>  "25",
  "mobi"=>  "25"

);

$renamed=array(

  "cz"=>    "Czech Republic",
  "com"=>   "international",
  "mobi"=>  "mobile"

);

?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php include("domains.php"); ?>      

<div id="prices">
  <table class="table">
    <tr><td>.cz</td><td>20$</td></tr> 
    <tr><td>.com</td><td>10$</td></tr> 
    <tr><td>.net</td><td>8$</td></tr> 
  </table>
  <table class="table">
    <tr><td>.info</td><td>8$</td></tr> 
    <tr><td>.biz</td><td>8$</td></tr> 
    <tr><td>.name</td><td>25$</td></tr> 
  </table>
  <table class="table">
    <tr><td>.mobi</td><td>25$</td></tr> 
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr> 
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr> 
  </table>
</div>    

<select id="zone">
  <option value="cz">Czech Republic</option>
  <option value="com">international</option>
  <option value="net">.net</option>
  <option value="org">.org</option>
  <option value="info">.info</option>
  <option value="biz">.biz</option>
  <option value="name">.name</option>
  <option value="mobi">mobile</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what you tried so far? I'll start by suggesting RTFM: http://php.net/foreach http://php.net/number_format

Comment: In fact, I understand how foreach works. However, the problem is with dividing a result table into tables with three rows, renaming and putting altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you a start. For further info, there's a lot of documentation at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/). When you want just three rows per table, you must use some row counter.

```
$row = 0;
foreach($price as $tld => $money) {
    if ($row == 0)
        echo "<table>\n";

    echo "<tr><td>$tld</td><td>$money</td></tr>\n";

    // close the table after three rows
    $row++;
    if ($row >= 3) {
        echo "</table>\n";
        $row = 0;
    }
}

// close the final table, if needed
if ($row > 0)
    echo "</table>\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job:

```
<div id="prices">
  <table class="table">
  <?php
  // Iterate through the list of domains and prices and print a row for each.
  foreach($price as $domain => $price) {
     print '<tr><td>.'.$domain.'</td><td>'.$price.'$</td></tr> '; 
  }
  ?>
  </table>
</div>

<select id="zone">
  <?php
  // Iterate through the list of domains and use the value of $renamed if exists.
  foreach(array_keys($price) as $domain) {
     print '<option value="'.$domain.'">'.isset($renamed[$domain]) ? $renamed[$domain] : $domain.'</option>'; 
  }
  ?>
</select>
```